# Creating new columns based on existing values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying create new columns based on a date range to see how much EMI is spent per month for every entry. In python please advise on how this can be done

Input File

```
Start Date  End Date    EMI
01/12/16    01/12/17    4800
09/01/16    09/01/17    3000
01/07/15    01/05/16    2300
```

and I want the output file to look like this

```
Start Date  End Date     EMI    06/16   07/16   08/16   09/16   10/16   11/16   12/16   01/17   02/17
01/12/16    01/12/17    4800    4800    4800    4800    4800    4800    4800    4800    4800    0
09/01/16    09/01/17    3000    0       0       0       3000    3000    3000    3000    3000    3000
01/07/15    01/05/16    2300    0       0       0       0       0        0      0       0       0
```

Please tell me your suggestions on implementing this using python.

Comment: I'm completely confused!  How did you come to the columns in the output?  What determines the values?

Comment: I have edited the sample file its basically if the EMI falls within a data range it has to poulate the column for that month with the EMI value

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need:

```
#reshape datetime columns to one, create datetimeindex
df1 = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['EMI', 'index'], value_name='date')
        .set_index('date')
#convert index to periodindex by month
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index, format='%d/%m/%y', errors='coerce')
              .to_period('M') 
#groupby by column index nad resample by month 
df1 = df1.groupby('index')
         .resample('M')
         .ffill()
         .drop(['variable', 'index'], axis=1)
         .reset_index()
#pivoting, fill NaN with 0, cast floats to int
df1 = df1.pivot(index='index', columns='date', values='EMI')
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int)
#change format of columns
df1.columns = df1.columns.strftime('%m/%y')
#concat original dataframe
df = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1)

print (df)
  Start Date  End Date   EMI  07/15  08/15  09/15  10/15  11/15  12/15  01/16  \
0   01/12/16  01/12/17  4800      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
1   09/01/16  09/01/17  3000      0      0      0      0      0      0   3000   
2   01/07/15  01/05/16  2300   2300   2300   2300   2300   2300   2300   2300   

   03/17  04/17  05/17  06/17  07/17  08/17  09/17  10/17  11/17  12/17  
0  ...     4800   4800   4800   4800   4800   4800   4800   4800   4800   4800  
1  ...        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
2  ...        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  

[3 rows x 33 columns]
```

Comment: Can you check my solution? `01/12/16` is `DDMMYY` or `MMDDYY` ?

Comment: The date format is MMDDYY I made this change to the statement `df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index, format='%d/%m/%y', errors='coerce')`

Comment: Also when I am executing this piece of code it was executing for 3 hours my total File size is only 180 MB `df1 = df1.groupby('index')
         .resample('M')
         .ffill()
         .drop(['variable', 'index'], axis=1)
         .reset_index()`

Comment: Data are condidental or not?

Comment: My actual Data has many columns Because of space I just picked the 3 columns for example

Comment: Data Is confidential

Comment: What is size of your `df` ? `len(df.index)`

Comment: The Length is 217, 250

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127801/discussion-between-yasin-mohammed-and-jezrael).